# Google Web Stater Kit to Server

Tags: web, sass, gulp

I am using the Google web starter kit to build myself a portfolio. I have everything up and running locally using gulp etc. I just want to know how I prepare my app to allow it to be placed on a web server? What are the processes to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Just running `gulp` will prepare your app for deployment.

https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/commands.md